# How to disable USB autosuspend on kernel 3.7.10 or above?

Tags: kernel, usb, power-management, suspend

I've updated my HTPC from kernel **3.7.10** to **3.10.7** and it seems **CONFIG_USB_SUSPEND** is now gone from the kernel options and included in PM.

The main problem I'm facing is that I have an external HDD and when suspending and waking up the HTPC, it isn't available to the system. The HDD wakes up (you can hear it spin up again), but when you try to access the mount point you get the following error:

```
ZOTAC ~ # ls /media
ls: reading directory /media: Input/output error
```

And on dmesg:

```
[  253.278260] EXT4-fs warning (device sdb1): __ext4_read_dirblock:908: error reading   directory block (ino 2, block 0)
```

In previous kernels, setting CONFIG_USB_SUSPEND=N would solve the problem, as the HDD would handle its hibernation by itself and the mount point was always accesible. When the HDD was on sleep and the HTPC needed something from the HDD's mount point, the HDD itself would wake up and operate without issues.

Right now I've tried the following without success:

1. Manually change **/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb*/power/control** to *"on"* instead of *"auto"*.
2. Manually change **/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb*/power/autosuspend** to *"-1"* instead of *"0"*.

But when waking up again the HTPC, the mount point is again inaccesible. As workarround I can unmount and remount the mount point and it works again without problems, but I'm sure there should be a way to avoid having the OS handle the usb autosuspend.

Any idea how to disable usb autosuspend on kernel 3.7.10 or above?

Comment: Does tail `/sys/bus/usb/devices/<BUS>-<DEVPATH>/power/persist` give you `1`? Does `grep CONFIG_PM_RUNTIME /boot/config-$(uname -r)` give you `y`? [power-management.txt](http://tomoyo.sourceforge.jp/cgi-bin/lxr/source/Documentation/usb/power-management.txt#L36)

Comment: `power/persist` gives `1` and I don't have any config file in `/boot`. `CONFIG_PM_RUNTIME=y` is configured in the kernel's `.config` file.

Answer (score 63):

For **Ubuntu** and **Debian**, `usbcore` is compiled into the kernel, so creating entries in `/etc/modprobe.d` will **NOT** work.  Instead, we need to change the kernel boot parameters.

Edit the `/etc/default/grub` file and change the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line to add the `usbcore.autosuspend=-1` option:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash usbcore.autosuspend=-1"
```

Note that `quiet splash` were already present options. So keep other options you have too.

After save the file, update grub:

```
sudo update-grub
```

And **reboot**.

Now check `autosuspend` value:

```
cat /sys/module/usbcore/parameters/autosuspend
```

And it should display `-1`.

### Additional Info

In the kernel documentation is stated that someday in the future this param will change to `autosuspend_delay_ms` (instead of `autosuspend`), but so far, still the same name.

The documentation for the value `-1` can be found in the kernel source file `drivers/usb/core/hub.c`:

```
1808:    * - If user has indicated to prevent autosuspend by passing
1809:    *   usbcore.autosuspend = -1 then keep autosuspend disabled.
```

Comment: This seems to be true for Debian as well.

Comment: Rael, thanks very much for this.  The same is true for the most recent version of Kali.  I added the above and my USB IRToy (v2) is now working properly.

Comment: I have a USB card in one of the mPCIE slots and just did not want the truth. Running Debian Jessie. This has solved my issue solving a huge headache, THANK YOU!

Comment: I tried this in Ubuntu 15.10 but the value is not applied (the value is 2). Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: I'm still on 14.04. But afaik, in the latest kernel versions, the param to change is `autosuspend_delay_ms`.

Comment: Thank you so much! After installing some updates on Ubuntu 15.10 my mouse stopped working, and this fixed it.

Answer (score 23):

According to the [kernel tree documentation](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/usb/power-management.txt), the autosuspend idle-delay time is controlled by the `autosuspend` module parameter in `usbcore`. Setting the initial default idle-delay to -1 will prevent the autosuspend of any USB device. You should still be able to to enable autosuspend for selected devices.

The `usbcore.autosuspend` kernel parameter can be set when the module is loaded manually:

```
$ modprobe usbcore autosuspend=-1
```

or by adding the following line to a configuration file in `/etc/modprobe.d`:

```
options usbcore autosuspend=-1
```

If `usbcore` is compiled into the kernel, parameter can be adjusted by adding the following to the kernel command line:

```
usbcore.autosuspend=-1
```

Lastly, the option may be adjusted at runtime by doing:

```
echo -1 >/sys/module/usbcore/parameters/autosuspend
```

The change will affect all new USB devices. Already existing devices will not be affected.

Comment: I have `usbcore` compiled into the kernel, but using the `modprobe.d` option doesn't seem to work. Despite `modprobe -c usbcore | grep autosuspend` displays it as `-1`, doing `cat /sys/module/usbcore/parameters/autosuspend` I get `2`

Comment: @Peter: `autosuspend` is deprecated. The new file is `autosuspend_delay_ms` which takes ms instead of seconds. [ref](http://tomoyo.sourceforge.jp/cgi-bin/lxr/source/Documentation/usb/power-management.txt#L108). But `power/control` set to `on` should have same effect.

Comment: @Sukminder, what should I configure then to keep autosuspend disabled forever? I've tried using `autosuspend=-1` in both `modprobe.d` and `kernel` parameter, but the HDD still suspends and doesn't wake up nicely.

Comment: @Peter: If I knew I'll tell you :). I'm only quoting what doc. says. Your *pt. 1* in your post should have done it as far as I can tell, I have no idea why it does not. Have you tried to set `autosuspend_delay_ms` to `-1`? (In `/sys/bus/usb/devices/<device>/power/autosuspend_delay_ms`)

Comment: I'm on kernel 4.4 and `autosuspend_delay_ms` is not there. But `autosuspend` IS.

Answer (score 4):

I have a similar issue with a *Microsoft Wheel Mouse Optical USB and PS/2 Compatible* since upgrading a [Linux Mint Debian Edition](http://www.linuxmint.com/download_lmde.php) system to kernel `3.10-2-amd64`. An inappropriate autosuspend by the kernel's [USB power management](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/usb/power-management.txt) was suspected. In Debian, this is compiled as the `usbcore` module into the kernel.

You can change this permanently by issuing at the command line:

```
sudo echo "options usbcore autosuspend=-1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/disable-usb-autosuspend.conf > /dev/null
```

Some kernels might require `autosuspend=0`, though.

If your system uses `initrd` (most probably does), then rebuild the `initrd` for your kernel.

For example:

```
uname -r
sudo dpkg-reconfigure linux-image-3.10-2-amd64
```

Reboot and check with:

```
cat /sys/module/usbcore/parameters/autosuspend
```

which should yield `-1` now.

Comment: I don't use `initrd` and the actions described here don't work in this case, as they we're answered before.