# Laptop keyboard and touchpad intermittently unresponsive on battery power

Tags: keyboard, laptop, touchpad, battery

I have a weird issue that I'm not sure how to troubleshoot.

I have a Razer Blade laptop that seems to work just fine when plugged into AC power. But when I unplug and go on battery power, the keyboard becomes intermittently unresponsive.

It's as if they're going to sleep randomly. It happens pretty often, even if I'm in the middle of typing something. It can take a few seconds for them to become responsive again.

My touchpad behaves similarly, but don't seem to be misbehaving as badly as the keyboard does.

I'm not really sure how to troubleshoot the issue. It seems to happen less if I boot up on AC power and then go to battery power, but if I boot up on battery power, it becomes almost unusable.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Output of `dmesg -t --level=alert,crit,err,warn`

```
x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS
ENERGY_PERF_BIAS: Set to 'normal', was 'performance'
ACPI Error: No handler for Region [VRTC] (0000000038115a5d) [SystemCMOS] (20210105/evregion-130)
ACPI Error: Region SystemCMOS (ID=5) has no handler (20210105/exfldio-261)
ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.EC0.RTEC due to previous error (AE_NOT_EXIST) (20210105/psparse-529)
ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.EC0._REG due to previous error (AE_NOT_EXIST) (20210105/psparse-529)
efifb: Ignoring BGRT: unexpected or invalid BMP data
nvme nvme1: missing or invalid SUBNQN field.
CRAT table not found
v4l2loopback: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
acpi PNP0C14:02: duplicate WMI GUID 05901221-D566-11D1-B2F0-00A0C9062910 (first instance was on PNP0C14:00)
acpi PNP0C14:03: duplicate WMI GUID 05901221-D566-11D1-B2F0-00A0C9062910 (first instance was on PNP0C14:00)
acpi PNP0C14:04: duplicate WMI GUID 05901221-D566-11D1-B2F0-00A0C9062910 (first instance was on PNP0C14:00)
platform regulatory.0: Direct firmware load for regulatory.db failed with error -2
iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
thermal thermal_zone7: failed to read out thermal zone (-61)
dell_smbios: Unable to run on non-Dell system
nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint

NVRM: loading NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  465.31  Thu May 13 22:24:36 UTC 2021
ACPI Warning: \_SB.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20210105/nsarguments-61)
nvidia-modeset: WARNING: GPU:0: Unable to read EDID for display device DP-4
nvidia-modeset: WARNING: GPU:0: Unable to read EDID for display device DP-4
kauditd_printk_skb: 254 callbacks suppressed
kauditd_printk_skb: 11 callbacks suppressed
kauditd_printk_skb: 15 callbacks suppressed
```

Comment: Please try this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91027/how-to-disable-usb-autosuspend-on-kernel-3-7-10-or-above

Comment: Thanks Artem. Before I saw this, I ended up solving it with something similar. Rather than disabling USB autosuspend completely, I set up a udev rule on my keyboard/touchpad device to disable autosuspend just for those devices. I basically followed this https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Power_management#USB_autosuspend and replaced the vendor and device ids with what I found using lsusb.

Comment: You can answer your own question then :-) Get some points for that :-)

Comment: Actually, that was a false positive. I seem to have the problem again. I also tried disabling autosuspend per the comment you left @ArtemS.Tashkinov, but that did not work either :( I'm still tinkering with it thought...

Comment: Any BIOS updates? Any BIOS options?

Comment: Any unusual messages in `dmesg`? E.g. `dmesg -t --level=alert,crit,err,warn`

Comment: I tried to look for bios updates but there don't seem to be any for my machine.

I ran the dmesg command and see the following. I don't really know how to interpret much of it but I do see some acpi errors.

I've edited my original post with the output....

Comment: Is this reproducible under Windows?

Comment: No, it works fine in Windows. I think I got to the root of it now.

I had laptop-mode-tools installed. I had disabled it but I just realized it was turning itself on automatically when I was on battery power. I just removed it completely and now my keyboard seems to be behaving properly.

After a little more searching on laptop-mode-tools and mouse/keyboard problems, I found this https://askubuntu.com/questions/760887/installed-laptop-mode-tool-16-04-now-usb-mouse-not-working-after-rebooting-unti

It looks like it was controlling USB autosuspend even though I disabled it.